# Tank on river when last to act and all bets in

Tags: rules, etiquette, home-game

I have this happen in my home game.  The guy is a weak so I don't want to kick him out.

Guy gets called on the river and opponent has shown his cards. The guy will tank showing or mucking his cards just to slow down the game.  How long do you give him before forfeiting his hand?

Comment: Just added some tags to the question that I thought were relevant.

Comment: Is it just showing on the river that he's slow at?  Does he ever slow-roll with winning hands?

Comment: @Dr.DrfbagIII Yes it takes him a long time to decide if he has the winning hand.  He has been betting the pot and he still has to read his hand.  I tell him just table your cards and the dealer will read the hand for you.  He does not get that play is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my opinion is, it's a home game, I'm assuming you're somewhat friendly, or at least feigning friendship at least(seen as you said you want to keep him because he is weak). A quick way to ruin a 'friendly' home game is to be strict on certain players, because you don't know how the other players will react to that either. My point is you could be strict and start calling the clock on this player, but maybe another player or two might not like that either, etc.

Now I ran a home game for years, and had a few players who were extremely slow, very similar situation to what you've described. My solution, friendly ribbing, as in a humoured, light hearted insult whenever it was on them. Nothing over the top, something that got a laugh but still got the message across to the player to not take 5 minutes.

My point is often home games have a bit of a looser feel with rules, and often you'll get players who only play home games because they're more relaxed and not as strict with rules. You know the mood, players and atmosphere of your game best so perhaps this isn't the answer but just a suggestion to try keep it friendly, well unless every other player at the game is super serious.

Answer (score 0):

If he is generally slow in the game (like his decisions) that's up to the table to decide how much time they give him. In live games and especially home games there is not really a time limit.

If the hand is finished (all decisions are made) and he is slow during showdown, well this is a real problem. This should be done in seconds, really. You need to check the reason he does it:

1) If he wants to hide his hand/plays: You need to better explain him the table rules (ex. if you get called and you lose, you either have to show hand or muck and lose the pot without showing your hand).

2) If he takes some time to process the board and his equity: Well, for a novice player that's acceptable up to a point, so I would give him the benefit of the doubt and maybe explain how to calculate the board quicker via some open card examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can **call the clock** ([Wikipedia Poker Glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_poker_terms#C))

60 seconds is usually a right amount of time.

But this shall not be done if player who delays the game shows his cards. It's more of a misconduct attitude in this particular case IMO. You can kindly say it first, then ask to play a little faster.

In home games, you can also set some specific rules, like a "home game gentlemen agreement" on what you expect, how players must behave, and other little things...

`@koita_pisw_sou` already gave some good points you shall consider before taking any action. Setting up some rules may help for future games though.

I think Daniel Negreanu once said something like this about callin the clock : *It's only okay against repeat offenders that are routinely taking too much time. Even then, a clock shouldn't be called unless a reasonable amount of time has passed. The bigger the pot, the more time that should be allowed*
(NOTE: can credit the 1st person who quoted this as I can recall where I saw it...)

Comment: May downvoter leave a comment and explain ?